# Add the values corresponding to same Id

Tags: sql

I am new to sql and  would like to find the solution for the following scenario .

The database table have the values as,

```
+--------+
|Id  |Val|
+--------+ 
| 1A | 1 |
+--------+  
| 1A | 2 |
+--------+  
| 1A | 3 |
+--------+  
| 1B | 4 |
+--------+  
| 1B | 2 |
+--------+
| 1C | 4 |
+--------+
```

But,I need exactly like below,

```
+--------+
|Id  |Val|
+--------+ 
| 1A | 6 |
+--------+  
| 1B | 6 |
+--------+  
| 1C | 4 |
+--------+
```

I have searched for the solution over the Internet , but unfortunately I could not find . Please help me finding the solution.

Comment: GROUP BY, combined with the aggregate function SUM!

Comment: Are you looking for a query that provides these result, or you want to change the values in the table?

Comment: Yes , I am looking for the query. @mikecurl91

Comment: You need to SUM, after a "GROUP BY"

Comment: can you please give the exact query ? @mikecurl91

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result using grouping and `SUM` function like this:

```
SELECT Id, SUM(Val) as Val
FROM table
GROUP BY Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   Id,
   SUM(Val) as SumVals  
FROM
   table_name  
GROUP BY
   Id
```

Consider to rename the summed value cols, in order to have a better expressivity of what the query have done.